# Magento onepage checkout taking too much time to submitting order information

Tags: magento, e-commerce, payment-gateway, ccavenue

My Magento onepage checkout ( http://www.decohome.in/index.php/checkout/onepage/ )  taking too much time(15-20 min) to submitting order information/ redirect to the next steps (Payment Gateway or COD success page) . And after redirecting to the payment gateway cc-avenue shows error page.

Below is the few information of the site:
website: http://www.decohome.in
The site is hosted on VPS server with 4GB RAM & 30 GB Disk space. Currently only 5.4 GB Disk space has been used.
 website template is "Theme578".

Can you guys please help to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear about following problems in your site:

1) You need to disable extension which override onepage checkout controller or observer which is executed after place order.

2) I have found that there are many cookies are generated and sent while you place order So disable code which generate cookies

3) check with other different payment method it is working in site or not.

4) while test refresh cache and storage in magento.